# how to find the current workspace classpath of eclipse automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, classpath, workspace

my question is about classpaths. For my plugin project in eclipse, to realize some process I need to search some files under eclipse of workspace. To do this, my project need a dynamic workspace classpath. This thing should find the classpath of workspace automatically and return a String and I need that string very much. by the way I am a very new about java and plugin but I need do that for my summer practise project, it is almost finished. Have a nice day

Comment: What do you mean by 'workspace classpath'? Individual Java projects have a classpath, the workspace does not.

Comment: here is what I mean, for example in my personal computer it is D:\\projects\workspace, i can embed this path into code but, when I install this plug in to another computer there is no such a workspace path. This path is only works for me. I want peace of code for to do find automatically @greg-449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

OR

`File` -> `Switch Workspace` -> `Other` the shown directory is your current workspace.

I hope this will help.

Comment: thank u for your reply but I tried this code ones ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString(); actually it didnt work, the error tells the ResourcePlugin can not be resolved. I dont know how to do it :/ @Ankur Mahajan

Comment: You have to add the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin to your plugin's dependencies so that you can use ResourcesPlugin

Comment: I have implemented whay you tell me, it will almost work but it gives me /appsw/projects/vatoz/runtime-EclipseApplication but I need /appsw/projects/vatoz/ws (it is myworkspace name) again thank you about your interest I am waiting your reply